# Using "or (foo = bar and bar = foo)" in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to do a query like this mysql query in Mongodb

```
select * from users where userid in (1,2,3,4) or (userid = 12 and status = 2)
```

But I can't figure out how to write it. I want to select all entries from a list of users and include the logged in users entries but only if they match a certain status. 
Posts from the other users in the array should be included with any status.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$or`:

```
db.users.find({
  $or: [
    { userid: { $in: [1, 2, 3, 4] } },
    { userid: 12, status: 2 }
  ]
})
```